# Compiling mp4v2 library on windows using QT creator

Tags: qt, mingw, configure

I need to compile the library mp4v2 in Windows 10 x64 using Qt creator.

The INSTALL file indicates ./configure should, but I'm using Windows so the command does not exist. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: On this site, please avoid, "hi", "thanks", "happy <anything>", and all that other chit chat in Questions and Answers. It's frowned upon here. Put that stuff in comments below questions or answers, or use the chat room.

Comment: Try installing [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com). That will give you a *very nice* powerful  bash shell command window to include UNIX-like projects on Windows. Makes Windows much friendly and more powerful.  I used it for years on Windows. It's very powerful. Much better (IMO) than Windows on command window/language (at least from awhile ago).  With cygwin you can install traditional UNIX-like components such as make, gcc, and hundreds of other familiar linux tools to build Windows projects with.